# make: *** No rule to make target 'install'. when trying to build git from source

Tags: apt, git

I am trying to install git on ubuntu 20 on my vmware work station

I am following [this tutorial article](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/install-git).

1. I installed the dependencies without any problems as well as clone a particular git as per the above article.
2. When I try to build the git and install the it under /usr it starts giving out errors.

   ```
   root@ubuntu:~# make all doc info prefix=/usr
   make: *** No rule to make target 'all'.  Stop.
   ```
3. I changed to directory to git and ran the command again

   ```
   root@ubuntu:/home/sudlo/git# make all doc info prefix=/usr
        CC fuzz-commit-graph.o /bin/sh: 1: cc: not found
   make: *** [Makefile:2379: fuzz-commit-graph.o] Error 127
   ```
4. I  have read a lot of articles but I have not got any kind of solutions.

Comment: `sudo apt install git`

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  as in Ubuntu Core 20?  (*yy* format is used only by *snap* based specialist releases, all server & desktop releases are *yy.mm* in format)

Comment: I ran  the command sudo apt install git - i keep getting the same error 

@guiverc - My bad this the version of ubuntu which i have

sudlo@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal

Comment: `cc: not found` suggests that you don't have a C compiler (`gcc`) installed

Comment: @guiverc ran the command as per your suggestion -

sudlo@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install build-essential
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.8ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: @steeldriver i dont think so i have c compiler

Comment: HI all , I re did the steps adding the following 

$ tar -zxf git-2.x.x.tar.gz
$ cd git-
$ make configure
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr
$ make all doc info
$ sudo make install install-doc install-html install-info

So far so good.. thanks guys for your help

Comment: Just to let you know, you don't have to build it from source if you installed it using `sudo apt install git` These are two different methods of installation. It is good practice to learn how to do stuff like this but usually the `apt` method is preferred. However, since you set the prefix to `/usr/` instead of using the default `/usr/share/`, I think the next `apt` update will overwrite the manually installed version which is good because you won't have to worry about manually installing future updates (you should be good to go).

Comment: @mchid thanks a lot my friend i will note it down